# Finding rows from table from values in Commas separated string

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a query and is a php starter

```
$minPrice = trim($_REQUEST['minPrice']);
            $maxPrice = trim($_REQUEST['maxPrice']);
            $minCarat = trim($_REQUEST['minCarat']);
            $maxCarat = trim($_REQUEST['maxCarat']);
            $color    = trim($_REQUEST['color']);
            $cut      = trim($_REQUEST['cut']);
            $clarity  = trim($_REQUEST['clarity']);
            $type  = trim($_REQUEST['type']);
```

type, clarity and cut are Strings separated by commans

e.g $type = "1000,1002,1001";

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM diamondsList WHERE price >= :minPrice AND price <= :maxPrice AND carat >= :minCarat AND carat <= :maxCarat AND cut IN(' . $cut . ') AND clarity IN ('.$clarity.') AND color IN ('. $color.') AND type IN (' . $type.')');
```

Error is

```
{"error":"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND clarity IN () AND color IN () AND type IN ()' at line 1"}
```

Firstly I am not sure the query is giving error at IN(' . $cut . ') What is wrong with syntax?

Secondly is query correct if syntax fixed?

after fixing i have query like this `searchDiamonds&minPrice=0&maxPrice=10000&minCarat=0&maxCarat=5&color=2000,2001&type=1000,1001&cut=3000,3001&clarity=4000,4001`

Two entries of table is listed as below

```
price carat type   color cut   clarity  
2000  2     1000   2000  3000  4000
```

However Nothing gets selected and i always get 0 result.

What should the query be

Comment: Have you tried to view the query to see what might be wrong?  Something like echo 'SELECT * FROM diamondsList WHERE price >= :minPrice AND price <= :maxPrice AND carat >= :minCarat AND carat <= :maxCarat AND cut IN(' . $cut . ') AND clarity IN ('.$clarity.') AND color IN ('. $color.') AND type IN (' . $type.')'

Comment: yes syntax error near cut IN(' . $cut . ') MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')

Comment: try to echo the full query to see what you really send to the mysql.

Comment: Can you show me what you see when you do an echo of the query string?

Comment: Is `$conn` a PDO object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't use empty string in `IN`. you need to check if for example `$cut` is set and change your query if its empty. like this:

```
$statement = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM diamondsList WHERE price >= :minPrice AND price <= :maxPrice AND carat >= :minCarat AND carat <= :maxCarat ' . (!empty($cut) ? ('AND cut IN(' . $cut . ')') : '') . ' AND clarity IN ('.$clarity.') AND color IN ('. $color.') AND type IN (' . $type.')');
```

I tested your query in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8d34/1) and it should work fine IF formatted correctly in php:

```
SELECT * FROM diamondsList 
WHERE price >= 0
AND price <= 10000 
AND carat >= 0 
AND carat <= 5 
AND cut IN(3000,3001) 
AND clarity IN (4000,4001) 
AND color IN (2000,2001) 
AND type IN (1000,1001)
```

Comment: ah crap that was the problem :) i fixed the $cut , now the string should be separated by commas right?

Comment: they should be seperated by commas. but note that if the values are not numbers but alphanumerical, you'd also need to quote them like `IN('a','b','c')`

Comment: can u please check out the second part

Comment: Can you show us what you see when you do an echo $cut ?

Comment: @bsoist yes the query is fixed now but I am not getting results of my query. i DID ask a second question that query is not returning values and i have given example. Can you check the query logic if its good

Comment: logic looks fine, but the query is probably not formatted right. Just add echo $cut and echo $clarity, etc. and then paste what you see for that here.

Comment: check the sqlfiddle i added

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be what you want, but I didn't test it.

```
$minPrice = trim($_REQUEST['minPrice']);
$maxPrice = trim($_REQUEST['maxPrice']);
$minCarat = trim($_REQUEST['minCarat']);
$maxCarat = trim($_REQUEST['maxCarat']);
$color    = trim($_REQUEST['color']);
$cut      = trim($_REQUEST['cut']);
$clarity  = trim($_REQUEST['clarity']);
$type  = trim($_REQUEST['type']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM diamondsList WHERE price >= $minPrice AND price <= $maxPrice AND carat >= $minCarat AND carat <= $maxCarat");

$field_info = array('cut' => $cut, 'clarity' => $clarity, 'color' => $color, 'type' => $type);
foreach($field_info as $f, $q) {
    if (!empty($q)) {
        $query .= " AND $f IN ($q)";
    } 
}

$statement = $conn->prepare($query);
```